# Llenar campos NULL con datos de otra fila

Tags: sql, sql-server

resulta que tengo una consulta que me trae 3 resultados, de los cuales 1 es totalmente null, la consulta esta construida por 2 tablas, la tabla de la izq es la que me trae el campo null, mientras que en la derecha vienen los campos completos, necesito llenar los NULL con la informacion de la otra tabla (en este caso seria la pierna premium) pero no he podido conseguirlo, agradeceria si alguien me puede ayudar o orientar en este caso
[image: Esta es la imagen donde se ve el null]

[image: y esta es la que tiene los campos completos, en este caso la pierna premium]

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(E0.FECHA) AS Anio, 
           MONTH(E0.FECHA) AS Mes, 
           DAY(E0.FECHA) AS Dia,
           CASE
               WHEN replace(E4.NUME, '', '') IS NULL
                    OR replace(E4.NUME, '', '') = ''
               THEN 'Manual'
               ELSE replace(E4.NUME, '', '')
           END AS HydraM, 
           E0.consecutivo, 
           E0.fecha, 
           E0.codtipodcto, 
           E0.codigo 'Nit', 
           E0.codbodega, 
           E3.nombre 'NomBode', 
           E1.codigo 'CodArt', 
           E2.nombre, 
           SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad
    FROM tblencfacturas E0
         INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas E1 ON E0.consecutivo = E1.consecutivo
         INNER JOIN tblarticulos E2 ON E2.codigo = E1.codigo
         INNER JOIN tblbodegas E3 ON E3.codbodega = E1.codbodega
         INNER JOIN tbltickets E4 ON E4.NUME = E1.hydra
    --Esto cambiaria de tu codigo
    WHERE YEAR(E0.FECHA) = '2019'
          AND MONTH(E0.FECHA) = '01'
          AND DAY(E0.FECHA) = '17'
          AND (CASE
                   WHEN replace(E1.hydra, '', '') IS NULL
                        OR replace(E1.hydra, '', '') = ''
                   THEN 'Manual'
                   ELSE replace(E1.hydra, '', '')
               END) = ('00083')
    GROUP BY YEAR(E0.FECHA), 
             MONTH(E0.FECHA), 
             DAY(E0.FECHA),
             CASE
                 WHEN replace(E4.NUME, '', '') IS NULL
                      OR replace(E4.NUME, '', '') = ''
                 THEN 'Manual'
                 ELSE replace(E4.NUME, '', '')
             END, 
             E0.consecutivo, 
             E0.fecha, 
             E0.codtipodcto, 
             E0.codigo, 
             E0.codbodega, 
             E3.nombre, 
             E1.codigo, 
             E2.nombre
) AS F0
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Anio, 
           MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Mes, 
           DAY(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Dia, 
           T0.D_FECHA AS T_Fecha, 
           T0.HOUR AS T_hora, 
           T0.NUME, 
           T1.CODIGO AS T_Codigo, 
           T1.NOMBRE AS T_nombre, 
           SUM(T0.WEIGHT) AS T_Cantidad
    FROM tbltickets T0
         INNER JOIN tblarticulos T1 ON T0.CODE = T1.CODALTERNO
    WHERE YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) = '2019'
          AND MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) = '01'
          AND DAY(T0.D_FECHA) = '17'
          AND T0.NUME = '00083'
    GROUP BY YEAR(T0.D_FECHA), 
             MONTH(T0.D_FECHA), 
             DAY(T0.D_FECHA), 
             T0.D_FECHA, 
             T0.HOUR, 
             T0.NUME, 
             T1.CODIGO, 
             T1.NOMBRE
) AS T0 ON F0.Anio = T0.T_Anio
           AND F0.Mes = T0.T_Mes
           AND F0.Dia = T0.T_Dia
           AND F0.HydraM = T0.NUME
           AND F0.CodArt = T0.T_CODIGO;
```

Comment: Entiendo tu problema, ni idea como solucionarlo sin tener todas las tablas que necesitas. Igual, a ver, alguno de los campos no es null... o no?

Comment: los campos que estan en la primer imagen, pero que no estan en la segunda pueden quedarse null, los demas si son necesarios

Comment: pasa que este es una factura,  la tabla completa es el ticket, y la tabla que contiene el null es la factura en si, cuando el cliente hizo el pedido pidio los 3 articulos, pero a la hora de pagar solo llevo 2, entonces al eliminarse el articulo quedo null, pero aun necesito que muestre la informacion del articulo que iba a llevar, solo que cantidad 0

Comment: Lo que pedis se puede hacer.. pero es muy complicado e implica recorrer de vuelta las tablas. O hacer un case por cada campo. Es dificil de ponerte una respuesta.

Comment: seria mediante un case anidado? , y mirar un case por cada campo?

Comment: un case campo por campo que verifique si es null y haga otra cosa en ese caso...

Comment: Me podrias dar un ejemplo? para tomarlo como referencia para los otros

Comment: es un case comun.. si el campo es null, tiras el que vos queres.. como el que escribiste para el campo E4.NUME. lo que pasa es que tenes que verificar todos los campos que no queres que queden en null...

Comment: Listo! Muchas gracias por la yuda @gbianchi

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien la verdad, pero no lo puedes resolver con isnull()?

Algo así:

```
SELECT YEAR(isnull(E0.FECHA,E1.FECHA)) AS Anio, 
       MONTH(isnull(E0.FECHA,E1.FECHA)) AS Mes, 
       DAY(isnull(E0.FECHA,E1.FECHA)) AS Dia,
       CASE
           WHEN replace(E4.NUME, '', '') IS NULL
                OR replace(E4.NUME, '', '') = ''
           THEN 'Manual'
           ELSE replace(E4.NUME, '', '')
       END AS HydraM, 
       isnull(E0.consecutivo,E0.consecutivo) consecutivo, 
       isnull(E0.fecha,E1.fecha) fecha, 
       isnull(E0.codtipodcto,codtipodcto) codtipodcto, 
       isnull(E0.codigo,E1.codigo) 'Nit', 
       isnull(E0.codbodega,E1.codbodega) codbodega, 
       E3.nombre 'NomBode', 
       E1.codigo 'CodArt', 
       E2.nombre, 
       SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad
FROM tblencfacturas E0
     INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas E1 ON E0.consecutivo = E1.consecutivo
     INNER JOIN tblarticulos E2 ON E2.codigo = E1.codigo
     INNER JOIN tblbodegas E3 ON E3.codbodega = E1.codbodega
     INNER JOIN tbltickets E4 ON E4.NUME = E1.hydra
```

Comment: necesito, que el campo que queda null, se llene con la info de la otra tabla, obviamente con el campo faltante